Child node stuck as it has exceeded 1MB (possibly a Firebase bug)
I have a user inside my /users/[id] Firebase Realtime Database doc that has 1,048,599 characters in its node, mainly due to them having too many favorites inside /users/[id]/favorites/[favorites], I read somewhere that the maximum is 1MB, therefore adding anything to this node programmatically is throwing trigger_payload_too_large error, along with the message TRIGGER_PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE: This request would cause a function payload exceeding the maximum size allowed..
While manually adding a child, it's showing An error occurred
Now, the problem is, not only can I not write anything to it, I can't update or delete any node. I tried to look for a way to delete in bulk, but apparently, that doesn't exist other than looping and using .remove().
When I attempt to update or delete, the update is not accepted (doesn't happen anything), and the delete just brings back the child node (for example inside /favorites), and when I attempt to update or delete them programmatically, it's throwing TRIGGER_PAYLOAD_TOO_LARGE: This request would cause a function payload exceeding the maximum size allowed. error.
What should be done, other than deleting the entire user (which I'm not sure would solve the issue)?


I read somewhere that the maximum is 1MB

The Realtime Database doesn't have a limit on how much data you can store under a single node. On the other hand, in Firestore there are some limits when it comes to how much data you can put into a document. According to the official documentation regarding usage and limits:

Maximum size for a document: 1 MiB (1,048,576 bytes)

As you can see, you are limited to 1 MiB total of data in a single document.
Getting back to the Realtime Database, the single limitation that is available is related to the size of a single event triggered by a write. This means that the write operations that are larger than 1 MiB will not trigger a Cloud Function invocation.
In such cases there are two options, you either denormalize the data, so you can have nodes that are less than 1 MiB, or you can use Firestore and try to limit the amount of data that you store in the document.

This is not the main issue, though. We have 60,000 users, and 8 experiencing this issue is not a problem for us, the problem is we need to assign a new ID to them to connect them to our SQL database, and writing/updating/deleting is not working on any of those 8 users, basically, they're "stuck". I should be able to delete a child node under favorites so that the total decreases to less than 1MB, which would let us insert a new child node.
